# how to detect difference between 2 points on the map and consider the zoom?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, annotations, point

I am using a map with some annotations, I want to group the nearest annotations in annotation group to not overlap in the design in case of user zoom out, but my problem is to how to know the distance between annotations and this distance should change when zooming in and out.

the distance should be between points with x and y formate note meters

So my question is to how to catch the difference between 2 points on the map and consider the zoom

```
// convert location to cLLocation
let cLLocation1 = CLLocation(latitude: post1Location?.lat ?? 0, longitude: post1Location?.lng ?? 0)
let cLLocation2 = CLLocation(latitude: post2Location?.lat ?? 0, longitude: post2Location?.lng ?? 0)


// this is return the dinsactence in metres but i don't need that
let distance = cLLocation1.distance(from: cLLocation2)



let annotaionPoint1 = MKMapPoint(cLLocation1.coordinate)
let annotaionPoint2 = MKMapPoint(cLLocation2.coordinate)

let xDistance = max(annotaionPoint1.x, annotaionPoint2.x) - min(annotaionPoint1.x, annotaionPoint2.x)
let yDistance = max(annotaionPoint1.y, annotaionPoint2.y) - min(annotaionPoint1.y, annotaionPoint2.y)
```

this is working but zoom in and zoom out no effect so I need zoom to make change

```
if min(xDistance, yDistance) <= 32 {
   /// action
}
```